# Convert Saved Currency Value In Firebase Firestore According To Country

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, currency-formatting

In my app users are allowed to upload and sell their goods but I only allowed users to add price tag in USD but after they have successfully uploaded what they want to sell I want to convert that price in USD to another currency for a user outside the US so I tried a code I found in another question but I can't yet properly understand how it works.

this is the code I tried

```
  public void setItemPrice(String ItemPrice) {
        NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.getDefault());
        price = mView.findViewById(R.id.post_price);
        price.setText(format.format(ItemPrice));
    }
```

but when i run the app crashes with this logcat error

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Number
    at java.text.DecimalFormat.format(DecimalFormat.java:640)
    at java.text.Format.format(Format.java:157)
```

this is how price tag is formatted in firebase

```
    postPrice.setCurrency("$");
    postPrice.setDelimiter(false);
    postPrice.setSpacing(false);
    postPrice.setDecimals(false);
```

this how it looks in firebase

[image]

Comment: So, what exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect and how is this question related to Firestore?

Comment: my app crashes with an error that it can not be converted

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Comment: i just updated my question

Comment: The error says that there's an incorrect argument, could it be that you first need to convert the object (probably String) to a "Number" type object or a primitive type number?